# Python's Selenium Collecting Data Problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to do a web scrapping project with python. It aims get into the website that i indicated at `driver.get('https://esarj.com/harita')` code and after that:

1- Collect all of the station's station name,station address,station working model data and put every each of them into the lists named StationNames,StationAddresses,StationWorkingModels

2- Take these lists and create a pandas dataframe that have these lists as columns and ["Station Name","Station Adress","Station Working Model"] list as column names

3- After that turn the dataframe a excel (.xlsx) file

I do not have any problem with second and third steps but when i try to do first step, i can just take one of the stations data but i want to collect every stations every data and store every part of the data at lists. I tried to solve this problem with loops but they does not work. My code is at below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Name = "//td[text()='Şarj Noktası:']//following::span[1]"
Address = "//td[text()='Adres:']//following::td[1]"
StationModel = "//td[text()='İstasyon Modeli:']//following::td[1]"

nameList=list()
addressList=list()
stationModelList=list()

path_chrome = r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\chromedriver.exe'
path_firefox=r'C:\Users\efede\OneDrive\Masaüstü\F\exeler\geckodriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_chrome)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driver.get('https://esarj.com/harita')

# Accept cookie
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Tamam')]"))).click()

names = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Name))).text

# click on Lokasyon tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Lokasyon']"))).click()
adresses = (wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Address))).text)

# click on Teknik tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Teknik']"))).click()
models = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, StationModel))).text

print(names)
print(adresses)
print(models)

driver.close()


zip_df=pd.DataFrame([NameList,AddressList,StationModelList],columns=["İstasyon Adı","Adres","İstasyon Modeli"])
zip_df.to_excel("ESARJ.xlsx",sheet_name="ESARJ(12.6.23)")
```

Output:

```
Highway Outlet Alışveriş ve Yaşam Merkezi
Ankara-İstanbul Otoyolu, 227. Km, Elmalık Mevkii, 14030 Bolu / Türkiye
PM 22kVA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please help me to solve this :)

Comment: You are using \*element\* function that returns first match, check there is \*elements\* to get list of all matches (element_to_be_clickable vs elements_to_be_clickable etc)

Comment: Hey did you tried my comment? You will get a list, so cant do .text, have to iterate the list and do .text for each element

Comment: I tried it a little ago but i encountered with there is no method named elements_to_be_clickable error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will do what you want. We take another approach, *i.e.,* intercept the API call, and extract the information you want. Should you find you can't run the code, run `pip install selenium-wire` (https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#accessing-requests)

```py
import json
import gzip
import pandas as pd

from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://esarj.com/harita")
# 1. get API requests
request = driver.wait_for_request("/api/stations")
# 1.a. response is gzipped
body = gzip.decompress(request.response.body)
body = body.decode()
# 1.b load json. Notice the response has leading newlines that need to be removed
data = json.loads(body[body.rfind("\n") + 1 :])
# 2. parse json
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[["storeName", "storeAddress", "modelName"]].to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But for a reason that i dont know i can't import seleniumwire libary. Have you ever encountered a issue like that?

Comment: I said you need to install this library (run that pip command) ^-^

Comment: I installed everything that you mentioned and followed every step you said already but it still does not import selenium-wire

Comment: Per that, my suggestion is to check the IDE you are using and the Python environment. You can try to follow the guide here: https://pastebin.com/mWG04XiY